# Getting this error: "Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager"

Tags: java, log4j

[image]I have included all the necessary log4j jar files and I don't understand why I'm still getting this error.

```java
package in.gstzen.einvoice;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jExample {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Hello World!\n");
        logger.debug("Log4jExample: A Sample Debug Message");
        logger.info("Log4jExample: A Sample Info  Message");
        logger.warn("Log4jExample: A Sample Warn  Message");
        logger.error("Log4jExample: A Sample Error Message");
        logger.fatal("Log4jExample: A Sample Fatal Message");
        System.out.println("Completed...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with complete error log and log4j configuration/properties you have used.

Comment: @Smile yes I have updated it.

Comment: Always use text when adding code or error log to question and not image. Also update your question with list of jars you have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please list the jars you added.

See here:
https://www.cwiki.us/questions/13469089/could-not-initialize-class-org.apache.logging.log4j.logmanager

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Please list the jars you added. 
https://www.cwiki.us/questions/13469089/could-not-initialize-class-org.apache.logging.log4j.logmanager

Comment: @ConstantineCh Thanks for the link! I added the log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.0.jar file and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a conflict between log4j versions 1 and 2.  Your class is importing version 1 classes, but the error message is in response to the spring framework not finding the jar files for version 2 classes.  You want to use one version or the other.

Version 1 is going to have classes with packages `org.apache.log4j.x`.
The jar will be called `log4j-1.x.x`

Version 2 is going to have classes with packages like `org.apache.logging.log4j.x`.
The jars will be named `log4j-core-2.x.x` and an the implementation like `log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.x.x`.

See this migration helper: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Note: If your classpath includes both the version 1 and version 2 jars resolution of the actual classes used can be somewhat random (and problematic).